# Data on Consumer Price Index (inflation rate) by state (USA)

Tags: data-request, usa, economics, cpi

I'm looking for a dataset that would contain historical CPI/inflation for each state of the US.
It seems that [bls.gov](https://bls.gov) should have this data, but it's either regional (South/North) or area (city/town) based data. [image: See screenshot here.]